# Как отслеживать удержание клавиши в новой системе ввода inputSystem?

Tags: unity3d

Вот рабочий код, который позволяет получать значение клавиш.

```
// Значения с устройств ввода (клавиатуры, джойстика и т.д.)
float XAxisInputValue;
float YAxisInputValue;

private InputSystem inputSystem;
private void OnEnable(){inputSystem.Enable();}
private void OnDisable(){inputSystem.Disable();}
private void Awake()
{
inputSystem = new InputSystem();

// Подписываемся на события.
//YAxis
inputSystem.Main.YAxis.performed+=YAxis_performed; // Нажатие клавиши.
inputSystem.Main.YAxis.started+=YAxis_started; // Удержание клавиши (?? на самом деле нет).
inputSystem.Main.YAxis.canceled+=YAxis_canceled; // Отпустили клавишу.
}


// Метод для нажатия клавиши
private void YAxis_performed(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext obj){YAxisInputValue = obj.ReadValue<float>(); }
// Метод для удержания клавиши.
private void YAxis_started(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext obj){YAxisInputValue = obj.ReadValue<float>();}
// Метод для отпускания клавиши.
private void YAxis_canceled(UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext obj){YAxisInputValue = obj.ReadValue<float>();  }
```

[image: Клавиша пробел]

Вот эта клавиша - пробел.

**Проблема в том, что и при нажатии и при удержании возвращается значение 1. В результате не ясно что это - однократное нажатие или удержание.**

Мне нужно как то отследить удержание клавиши, подобно этому коду

```
// Если нажали на пробел - значит начали прыжок
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) isJumping=true;

// Если отпустили пробел - значит прыгаем.
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space)) jumpNow=true;
```

Причем не привязываясь к конкретным клавишам. Ведь мы их должны привязывать в визуальном редакторе InputSystem.
То есть вот этот код

```
jumpInput = new InputAction("Jump", InputActionType.Button);
jumpInput.AddBinding("<Gamepad>/buttonSouth"); // кнопка A на геймпаде
jumpInput.AddBinding("<Keyboard>/space"); // пробел на клавиатуре
```

Мягко говоря странный так как дублирует визуальный редактор InputSystem. мы там задаем биндинги, а теперь дублируем/задаем это в коде. Это не нормально.

**Как отслеживать удержание клавиши из моего раздела YAxis?**

Comment: Нет никакого дублежа. Создание `InputAction` и биндинг через код, только для тех случаев, когда в игре можно менять управление в настройках. Для того что бы узнать значение импута есть [ReadValue<TValue>()](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.CallbackContext.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_InputAction_CallbackContext_ReadValue__1) и калбеки фаз.

Comment: То есть предлагаете не использовать визуальный редактор, а биндить в коде?